# Grafana tempo architecture: Query frontend and querier components

Tags: grafana-tempo

[This](https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/operations/architecture/#query-frontend) tells about Query frontend component in grafana tempo architecture.

I am not very clear about it.Like:

> Internally, the Query Frontend splits the blockID space into a
> configurable number of shards and queues these requests.

How does it get access to blockid? Does Query frontend first fetches blockid data from backend,and then shards it? And what do sharded queries mean here?

Also, in diagram, Querier comes after query frontend. So query frontend sends queries to querier or querier pulls queries from query frontend, and then act on them?